# Por que no se cambia la visibilidad? Javascript

Tags: javascript, css3

Hice este código:

```js
document.addEventListener("DomContentLoaded", function(){

  var home = document.getElementById("home");
  var set = document.getElementById("settings");
  var binds = document.getElementById("binds");

  home.onclick = function(){
    
    document.getElementById("nickname").visibility = "visible";    
  };
  

  set.onclick = function(){
    
    document.getElementById("settings2").visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("nickname").visibility = "hidden";    
 
  };
  binds.onclick = function(){
    
    document.getElementById("binds2").visibility = "visible";
  };
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #main {
      
      position: absolute;
      top: 12%;
      left: 25%;
      width: 350px;
      height: 410px;
      background-color: #CBCBCB;
      
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      background-color: #A09C9C;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    li {
     float: left;
      
    }
    li a{
      display: block;
      padding: 20px 15px;
      color: white;
      
      
    }
    li a:hover:not(active) {
      
      background-color: black;
      
    }
    li a.active {
      
      background-color: black;
      
    }
   
    
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <ul>
      <li id="home" ><a class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li id="settings"><a>Settings</a></li>
      <li id="binds"><a>Binds</a></li>
      
    </ul>
    
 
    <div id="nickname">
      
     <input style="margin-left: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" type="text" placeholder="{ogarpw}Nickname"/>
  <input style="border: 2px solid white; " type="button" value="Jugar"/>
    </div>
    <div id="settings2" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <h1 style="text-align: center;">Settings!</h1>
      <p> Cualquier configuracion disponible..</p>
    
    </div>
    <div id="binds2" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <h1 style="text-align: center;">Binds!</h1>
      <p> Cualquier bind disponible..</p>
    </div>
    
    
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1) Se supone que al hacer *click* en 'settings', oculta el contenido del div `nickname` y muestra el contenido del div `settings2`, pero no es asi, por que me falla ese aspecto?

Comment: Porque tienes que usar `style`: `elemento.style.visibility = 'visible'`.

Comment: [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mapeo de las propiedades css en los elementos se hacen en la propiedad `style`, la cual almacena un objeto [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) que es básicamente una especie de objeto literal al ser conformado por *clave - valor*.

Yu código debe ser:

```
document.getElementById("nickname").style.visibility = "visible";
```